# How to generate Page Token to access API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

so I'm trying to generate a Page token for my facebook messenger bot so that it can start using the apis for testing/development.

[image: dropdown menu]

However, when I select a page, I run into this error message at the top

[image: error]

And after I click continue, it still generates these errors

[image]
[image]

I'm just trying to get a bot up for testing, so I don't want to go through the hassle of review and what not, how do I get past these errors and get a Page token for use? I have checked and made sure I'm the admin of both the app and the page, and the app is still in developmental mode, and also tried making new facebook accounts just for this app but have still run into the same error.

Thanks,
Ng

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you have admin permission to the Facebook Page (I guess you have as it is displayed there). Are you also an admin of the Facebook Page? During the authorization, can you double check if all permission are set by clicking on "Choose what you allow".

If you'd like just to test something, I would recommend 3rd party tools like [Amio.io](https://amio.io) where you can start in few seconds instead of creating an app, approving, etc.

> Disclimer: I work for Amio. :-)